# Call "function" from outside of scope

Tags: node.js, websocket

I need to something in the likes of this:

```
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(webSocket) {
    function foo() {
        //do stuff
    }
});

webSocketServer.broadcast = function (data) {
    foo();
};
```

But that will define the function over and over again when new clients connects, and I don't want to do a loop in the .broadcast since there can be up to 100k+ client. I've though about emitting somehow, but can't solve the logic... What can I do?

Comment: can't you define your function globally for the callers and send parameters to it?

Comment: @micnic I don't follow you, what do you mean? I need a function/event/whatever to be fired inside the connection event when .broadcast is called...

Comment: @user3054852 Your edit solves the immediate problem that I pointed out but it's still not clear what you are trying to do exactly. My initial thought was the same a micnic's but your reply to micnic's comment does not clarify. (And I really don't see what is not understandable in micnic's comment.)

Comment: @Louis What is unclear for me is who the caller is, where I should define the function and what parameters I should send to it, so basicly everything...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to capture variables in the definition of `foo` then you can just define it outside of the `.on('connection'`... block.

If you do need to capture variables in `foo`, then you need to do it the way you have it. Depending on the complexity of `foo`, this might be 9-10ms to do 100,000 times, so for many use cases it should be fine.

Also, defining a function using the `function foo() {` syntax won't hoist the function definition, and so you won't have access to it outside the scope of the function where its defined.